# Flex App works locally ☼ Though once online, NetConnecton dosen't connect nor fault Event fires

Tags: flash, apache-flex, adobe, host

I'm debugging my app locally that fetches data connecting to a AMFPHP gateway on my host. When I run it locally, it works perfectly.

I have added the crossdomain.xml file at the root of the domain.

Now, when I uploaded the release onto my host, the NetConnection gives me back nothing, not even a Status (fault) event.

**Flex SDK 4.1.0**

**Flash Player 10.1**

**crossdomain.xml** in the root of my domain:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?> 
<!DOCTYPE cross-domain-policy SYSTEM "macromedia.com/xml/dtds/cross-domain-policy.dtd">; 
<cross-domain-policy> 
   <allow-access-from domain="*" /> 
</cross-domain-policy>
```

Any suggestions as to why?

Comment: What version of the  Flex SDK, what Flash Player version and whats in the crossdomain.xml file? Flash 10 requires different crossdomain.xml than flash 9 for instance.

Comment: I have changed the crosspolicy.xml to accomodate for the Flash 10.1 player to:
`<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE cross-domain-policy SYSTEM "http://www.macromedia.com/xml/dtds/cross-
domain-policy.dtd">
 <cross-domain-policy>
 <site-control permitted-cross-domain-policies="all" />
 <allow-access-from domain="*" />
 <allow-http-request-headers-from domain="*" headers="*"/>
</cross-domain-policy>`
Yet, still nothing rendering on the swf located on the host. Works fine on my local.

Comment: download charles, and see what the request/responses are, hopefully that will help you.

Answer (score 0):

The proper crossdomain.xml file policy for Flash 10.1 and over. (change ***** for security). The error was from my end.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?> 
<!DOCTYPE cross-domain-policy SYSTEM "http://www.macromedia.com/xml/dtds/cross-domain-policy.dtd"> 
<cross-domain-policy> 
     <site-control permitted-cross-domain-policies="all"/> 
     <allow-access-from domain="*" /> 
</cross-domain-policy>
```